# Plotting: single big column and its frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I am new to Python so sorry in advance for my newbie questions and mistakes.

I have tried to find it myself, but I feel like I am missing some of the basic information.

The goal is to plot this information in a bar plot.

I have separated a column from pandas dataframe, 43169 rows × 1 columns. Example:

```
user_lifetime
0   947.000000
1   951.000000
2   523.000000
3   741.000000
4   840.000000
5   563.000000
```

To plot this, I need to get the frequencies of each unique value, right?
Found this:

```
 lifetime=df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)).
```

It produces a table like that

```
              user_lifetime
15947.000000    4677
15916.000000    1951
2017.000000     1917
2016.000000     1131
2014.000000     445
```

Which seems what I was aiming for, but it does not seem to be the table I can use for plotting.

Any suggestions on what I have missed?
My top package priority is ggplot as we have used these examples in a lecture.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with python, but ggplot will do the counts for you if you use the correct geom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain [pd.Series.value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`plot(kind='bar')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) (or [`plot.bar()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), new in version 0.17.1 and perfectly equivalent)

```
df['user_lifetime'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

---

You might end up with a ton of bars though... Maybe you're looking for a **histogram**, where each value ends up in bins? [`DataFrame.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) is what you would need.

If I use some random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,1000,(40000,1)), columns=['user_lifetime'])
```

I would have way too many bars if I used the above. So I want a histogram, with say 20 bins:

```
df.user_lifetime.hist(bins=20)
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: Yep, ton of bars happened to the point where I don't even feel like showing it to anyone. But the second one looks like what I got:

Comment: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/37d0d580e11c6c2699d2c881fd1187a7.png)

But that is not what I have expected, it does not seem to count the frequencies or else there would not be that many empty gaps.

Comment: It sure does count the number of values that fall in each bin (or bucket). You may want to play with the number of bins, 20 might be too much for you. (Also, this is a good example of why you should always try to include what your desired output is in your question)

Comment: I added the random data I used to create the above graph.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my interpretation was not correct, I get it now, thank a lot :)